# Robotux tray icon doesn't show up

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu

when I start Robotux on Lubuntu 13.04, I get the notification that it has started, and the icon doesn't appear. Does any1 have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of Robotux, and just for other people who might be reading this:
It's usually better to contact me via mail or the contact form on http://abatzill.de/cms/index.php/Contact . I usually don't check Askubuntu.

As for your problem:
This seems to happen from time to time in Robotux 0.2. I wasn't able to reproduce it myself, but got a few hints in order to hopefully fix it in Robotux 0.3 that will be released soon.

As a workaround, you can delete the file "~/.config/robotux/storedmacros". This will clear all your saved macros, but at least it will make robotux work again.

In order to delete the file in your file-manager, you need to make it show "hidden files" by pressing Ctrl+H.

Comment: This is a terrible "workaround" (Delete all data to make it work again)

Comment: I noticed this problem doesn't occur if you're not trying to delete more than 1 macro at once (by selecting multiple checkboxes and clicking "OK").